# Cannot see container images in Gitlab Container Registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, container-registry

I configured GitLab (GitLab Enterprise Edition 12.9.3) on Ubuntu (on Virtual Box) including Container Registry ("insecure-registries" enabled for Docker).

When I try to retrieve the container images in GitLab, I'm getting "There are no container images stored for this project" (but when I use a curl-call, I see the images). I expect to see the container images.

Looking at the registry log, I see:

time="2020-04-23T21:34:01.853271246Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code="name unknown" err.detail=map[name:joachimaltmeyer/sanfrancisco2] err.message="repository name not known to registry" go.version=go1.11.2 http.request.host="192.168.178.42:5000" http.request.id=bcffcac6-6373-4673-a4b0-77a157b35dea http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="192.168.178.42:33436" http.request.uri="/v2/joachimaltmeyer/sanfrancisco2/tags/list" http.request.useragent="Faraday v0.15.4" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=1.167887ms http.response.status=404 http.response.written=137 vars.name="joachimaltmeyer/sanfrancisco2"

I'm not an Gitlab expert, but it seems to me that the branch is missing i.e. e.g. "/v2/joachimaltmeyer/sanfrancisco2/tags/list" is called instead of "/v2/joachimaltmeyer/sanfrancisco2/master/tags/list"

I found [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/31846) which describes the problem from my perspective, but there is no solution described.